# VB.NET - Regex.Replace Capitalise Words In Sentence

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to replace any occurrences of specific words with capitalized versions of the same word.

Code:

```
Dim Sentence As String = "select * from table where field = 1"
Dim Words As New List(Of String)({"SELECT", "FROM", "UPDATE", "WHERE"})

For Each w As String In Words
    Sentence = Regex.Replace(Sentence, "??", w, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
loop
```

You can probably see where I'm going with this...

[Here is reference for `Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taz3ak2f(v=vs.110).aspx), but I can't figure it out.

**Edit:** I only want to replace "words" that begins/ends with a space or line-break or beginning/end of file. So something like: `^m?(word)$m?` ?

Comment: So, only specific words that are stored in a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - simply use `\b` either side of the word to represent any white space or newline char:

```
Dim Sentence As String = "select * from table where field = 1"
Dim Words As New List(Of String)({"SELECT", "FROM", "UPDATE", "WHERE"})

For Each w In Words
    Sentence = Regex.Replace(Sentence, "\b(" & w & ")\b", w, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use your words as pattern and as replacement:

```
For Each w As String In Words
    Sentence = Regex.Replace(Sentence, w, w, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Next
```

But note that this does not take e.g. whitespace or quoted text into account; so depending on your actual use case, this may or may not work for you.

---

Here's a more advanced regex:

```
Dim Sentence As String = "select * from table where field = 'fooselectfar foo select foo' "
Dim Words As New List(Of String)({"SELECT", "FROM", "UPDATE", "WHERE"})

For Each w As String In Words
    Sentence = Regex.Replace(Sentence, "(^|(?<=\W))" & w & "(?=\W)(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)", w, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Next
```

`Sentence` is now `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = 'fooselectfar foo select foo'`.

Comment: Hi Sloth, do you know how I can account for whitespace before/after words?